# Using a shared library without source code

Tags: go, compilation, shared-libraries

I am building the shared library which can be used for my python program using command.

`go build -o program.so -buildmode=c-shared myprogram/program.go`

However, it seems that for me to use the shared library on another machine, I have to include all the source code. Otherwise, I would get `OSError: invalid ELF header`.

Is using the shared library without source code possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Library is a binary artifact and will only work on same architecture as it was built for. `OSError: invalid ELF header` means the library is for different architecture (e.g. library built on x86_64 Linux won't load on arm Linux, x86_64 MacOS X and so on).

Use without source code is perfectly possible if you build library binaries for all architectures (CPU and OS) where your users intend to use it.